# Ruby on Rails Populate second dropdown based on 1st dropdown's selection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently, I have a dropdown (`<options>`) that is pulling back a list of states in a database, and I want a second dropdown to appear and provide a list of cities associated with that state once the first dropdown is selected.

Here are some samples of the files that I have to hopefully provide some clarification:

models/states.rb:

```
class States < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :cities
end
```

models/cities.rb:

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :state
    # States are referenced by table column state_id
end
```

Inside of the view that I'm working with, I have this:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :state_id %><br>
    <%= select(:city, :state_id, State.all.collect {|c| [c.name, c.id]}, {prompt: "Select state"}) %>
  </div>
```

but of course this only populates the first dropdown. Is there any easy way to accomplish my goal using any Ruby on Rails helpers? Or do I have to use ajax and jquery?

Comment: You need to use JavaScript if you don't want a page refresh. If you don't want to use JavaScript, then you need to have the user submit the form after selecting a state and load the page again with the city dropdown in place.

Comment: there is also nice episode about that: [dynamic-select-menus](http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus)

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot. I ran across that but wasn't sure if it still applied. Going to go check that out now. Much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [rails multiple form selects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583321/rails-multiple-form-selects)